# Select Into removes IDENTITY property from target table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, identity

I am doing an exercise which removes the IDENTITY property from the target table when using a select into statement.

> source table name: Sales.Orders
>   column name: orderid
>   column property: int type, not null, defined as a primary key, identity property is defined on the column)
>   Column name: custid
>   column property: int type, foreign key, null
>   target table name: Sales.MyOrders

In the 70-461 exam book - Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012, chapter 10 p336:

1. it gives code

   ```
   ISNULL (orderid + 0, -1) as orderid,
   --this will remove IDENTITY property and make column not null
   ```
2. Make custid column not null in target able

   ```
   ISNULL (custid, -1) as custid, --make column not null
   ```

I don't understand these two code items, though it works.

Could someone tell me the concepts behind the code?

The code provided in the book:

```
select isnull (orderid + 0, -1) as orderid, 
isnull (custid, -1) as custid, 
empid,
isnull (cast(orderdate as date), '19000101') as orderdate,
shipcountry,
freight
into Sales.MyOrders
from Sales.Orders
where shipcountry = N'Norway';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviors you're curious about are explained [in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx):

> When an existing identity column is selected into a new table, the new column inherits the IDENTITY property, unless one of the following conditions is true:
>   
> ...
> - The identity column is part of an expression.
>   
> ...
> If any one of these conditions is true, the column is created NOT NULL instead of inheriting the IDENTITY property.

And in [this thread from UC](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/7af9edf4-9b26-4a00-b14a-8a6263f22675):

> Metadata is determined based on the source column and expressions used
>   in the SELECT list. Below are the rules:
>
> Any expression that uses a built-in function like SUBSTRING, LEFT, RIGHT etc (except ISNULL) for example is considered as NULLable by the
>   engine. So if you use CAST(somecol as char(8)) then the expression is NULLable.
>   
> ...
>   So to make an expression or column in the SELECT list not null then use ISNULL around the column or expression.

Comment: Hello Aaron, thanks for answering my question. I understood what makes a column is nullable or not null when using Select...Into statement in SQL Server.